# How best to convey a message from one Fragment to its parent (onActivityResult equivalent)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

OK I know that I may be thinking about this the wrong way but ...

A) I have activity A loading Fragment F1 which loads fragment F2. F2 performs an action which should result in it being closed and then F1 performing a certain action based on how it was closed.

B) Now because I'm also supporting a single pane, non-fragment, version F1 also loads F2 indirectly via a startActivityForResult call. This means that when F2's wrapper activity is finished F1 recieves an onActivityResult call and F1 can do what it needs to do.

However, I'm struggling to see the best way to implement what I want for (A). I have F2 calling back to activity A to pop it off of the stack. Should I then be looking at passing a message to F1 to do what it needs to do? Alternatively (I suppose F1 could be responsible for popping F2 off of the stack).

What I'm wondering is whether I'm on the right track with regards passing messages back and forwards via the parent activity or is there a more direct way of F1 responding to F2 performing something that requires it to be closed and F1 do what it needs to do.

Thanks in advance. Peter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your fragments are closely tied together, just don't run them in separate activities.  For the single pane case you can just switch fragments within one activity.

Otherwise, if you do want to separate them between activities, you need to use the `onActivityResult()` model for propagating results back, and in the dual-pane case "emulate" it by just having the second call `onActivityResult()` of the first fragment.  Note that `Fragment.setTargetFragment()` includes a request code argument to facilitate this.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate emulation. BTW project deadlines mean large changes are not an option so where I have (pre-fragment) activity A invoke B invoke C, on a tablet I have 2 panes where B's layout is replaced by C's in the right pane. Given existing onActivityResult code and the need for a single pane on the phone I have taken the approach of having B and C be wrapper activities and moved each of their functionality into a Fragment. That way for each call to startActivitiy... I can either still make that call or load up a fragment instead. I'd be interested to know whether that makes sense.

Comment: I need to try this but I'm guessing that when F1 loads F2 I can call F2.setTargetFragment(this, code) and in F2 I can call getTargetFragment() and if it returns non-null call target.onActivityResult(...). There is also the case where F2 may actually be loaded via its wrapper activity but I'm guessing that getTargetFragment will return null so I can handle that case appropriately. Documentation all a little sketchy and not sure whether FragmentManager.putFragment could be used...

Answer (score 7):

> I have activity A loading Fragment F1 which loads fragment F2

IMHO, fragments should not load other fragments. Activities load fragments, based upon available screen space. Fragments should neither know nor care whether any other fragment exists in the current activity, or if other fragments are in other activities.

> I have F2 calling back to activity A to pop it off of the stack. Should I then be looking at passing a message to F1 to do what it needs to do?

Yes.

> What I'm wondering is whether I'm on the right track with regards passing messages back and forwards via the parent activity or is there a more direct way of F1 responding to F2 performing something that requires it to be closed and F1 do what it needs to do.

I would not have F1 even know that F2 exists, or vice versa. When the user does something in F1 that should result in a major context shift (e.g., display some other fragment/activity), F1 should let the hosting activity know, perhaps via a listener interface registered with F1 (to support multiple possible hosting activities). The activity would then arrange for F2 to appear, either in its own activity or in another activity. Similarly, when F2 wraps up, it would let its hosting activity know via a listener interface, and that activity can route control back to the appropriate spot.

I am somewhat skeptical of your whole "F2 performs an action which should result in it being closed" approach, unless F2 is a `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Thanks but I have to somewhat disagree. My pre-ported app had activity A invoke B invoke C for which it is legitimate for B to know about C and modify its behaviour using the result of C (onActivityResult). The fact that for my fragment version when running on a tablet I have a dual pane (single on a phone) for which fragment Bf in the right pane is replaced by fragment Cf should make little difference as to what Bf should know about Cf. Given it's also legitimate for Bf to fire off an activity and get its result, again I don't see why it should not be able to do this easily with a fragment.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer. I will redesign what I'm working on now. Thank you!